# Windows Shortcut Key for `

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I use MySQL a lot and also Pseudo code editors, I am trying to find out the shortcut for this character

```
`
```

(backtick)

```
// Example
SELECT * FROM `latest_orders` LIMIT 3000
```

Preferably on a Windows Machine (UK Keyboard)

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: The character is called backtick, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be the button left of your '1'. See this pic from wikipedia:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is the character, from my keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On my keyboard it is the key below the escape key, top left hand side of the keyboard, that's on a standard UK desktop keyboard.